# Saving a Graphics content to a file

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap

I have some code where I draw a function graph into a `PictureBox` graphics. The code is implemented in the `Paint` event. At some point I want to save a bitmap of the content of the graphics in a file.

I already read the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4305168/saving-graphics-to-bitmap-outside-of-paint), and didn't found what I was looking for.

What I need is both to draw in the PictureBox (or any other control that you suggest) so that I don't loose the drawing when the control is hidden or something (so I think I cannot `CreateGraphics()`) *and* be able to save that drawing in a button's click event.

I'm willing to put the drawing logic out of the `Paint` event if necesary.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063505/c-sharp-how-to-save-a-picturebox-control-as-a-jpeg-file-after-its-edited)

Comment: Hang on I think this is easy, you don't actually want to save the image to a file to use after you close the program and start it again, you just want it to stay there when you minimze the window and reopen.  I think you are looking for persistant graphics. If I am correct, can you post some of your code so we could see it and help out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went ahead and answered the question based on my assumption,

I created a new `Winforms` application

I added a panel and a button
I created a `Bitmap` named `buffer`, and in the `Form1` constructor, initialized it to the size of the panel.  Instead of drawing directly to the panel, I draw to the `Bitmap`, then set the panels background image `buffer`;  This will add persistance to your graphics.  If you truly wish to write to a file, I can show you that.  Just ask.

To write to file you will need this namespace reference :

```
using System.IO;
```

I added the `ImageToDisc` function you were asking for.

*Here is the Code :*

```
Bitmap buffer;
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    panel1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
    buffer = new Bitmap(panel1.Width,panel1.Height);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(buffer))
    {
        g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, 100, 100,100,100);
    }

    panel1.BackgroundImage = buffer;
    //writes the buffer Bitmap to a binary file, only neccessary if you want to save to disc
    ImageToDisc();
    //just to prove that it did write it to file and can be loaded I set the mainforms background image to the file
    this.BackgroundImage=FileToImage();
}

//Converts the image to a byte[] and writes it to disc
public void ImageToDisc()
{
    ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
    File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:\test.dat", (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(buffer, typeof(byte[])));
}

//Converts the image from disc to an image
public Bitmap FileToImage()
{
    ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
    return (Bitmap)converter.ConvertFrom(File.ReadAllBytes(@"c:\test.dat"));
}
```

Comment: Why are you converting the image to a `byte[]` to save it?  Just use `Image.Save()`.

Comment: I dunno, It made sense to me to save it to a binary format.  I suppose there is no reason not to save it to an image format.

Comment: Thanks, I think that will make it. Point taken on the `Image.Save` from @EdS also.