# When I minimize my application all of my drawings disappears

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, graphics

I am building a C# app that shows the trajectory of a cannonball. But when I minimize it the trajectory I have drawn to a picture box are gone when I bring it back up. Is there an easy way to stop this?

Comment: See this:  http://bobpowell.net/picturebox.htm

Answer (score 2):

I bet your drawing in the mouse event. Use the onpaint event and you should be good to go.

Edit:

Here is a decent drawing tutorial using the onpaint() event:

http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial50_Drawing-with-Csharp.html

Comment: OnPain sounds painful. In any case you should add that you need some form of retained mode drawing in that case, i.e. you need to have a structural copy of *what* you are drawing in `OnPaint`. This could be a Bitmap in memory you're painting on and you're copying to the PictureBox, it could be the individual points or a path of that trajectory so you can easily re-draw it. In any case the fix isn't as trivial as exchanging one event handler for another and the person asking obviously doesn't really know this.

Comment: HaHa thanks for pointing that type out Joey! Good advice too.

Comment: @AlesTrunda Resurrected a 5 year answer :) Sorry the link died.

Answer (score 0):

When the window is restored it will need to redraw the form. If you do not have your drawing as part of the paint event, then it will not be redrawn.

Answer (score 0):

This question is very similar to this one

[Saving a Graphics content to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10737859/saving-a-graphics-content-to-a-file/10738741#10738741)

As the others have already stated the problem is when you draw onto a graphics object, there is nothing retained.  It is called persistent graphics.  Sometimes you want this behavior, more often than not you don't.

You should do your drawing onto a bitmap, then copy the bitmap to your picturebox.Image. The other option as stated in the other answers, is do your drawing routines in the OnPaint Method.

Read my answer in the above. The title is misleading, he thought he had to save to a file to gain persistence, but we showed him otherwise.

**EDIT** Here is the important code from the above link

```
Bitmap buffer; 
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    panel1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
    buffer = new Bitmap(panel1.Width,panel1.Height);
    //Make sure you resize your buffer whenever the panel1 resizes.
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(buffer))
    {
        g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, 100, 100,100,100);
    }
    panel1.BackgroundImage = buffer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i was having same problem just used mainp.refresh() after event change

mainp was my panel in which i was drawing my all graphics